# Interpreting normalized value in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients, normalization, odds-ratio

I'm trying to interpret results from my logistic regression. I normalized the values between 0 and 100 because I had many variables with different units.

My intercept is -0.741 and I'm using that to calculate probability P0

For the variable investment cost, I calculated the unit change as function of the max and min original values. The coefficient of this variable is -8.247 and is significant.

Can you please check if my reasoning and interpretation are correct ? Thanks a lot !

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV! What is your specific question here (beyond "checking reasoning")? Generally on CV you want to narrow a query down to one major question so people can answer it, otherwise the questions will either get skipped or closed (for not having focus). Here there are a lot of notes about the summary of your analysis, but its not clear what you are questioning.

Comment: My question is how to interpret my results and wether the interpretation I suggested was correct. Thanks!